# What is the best approach to cancel realtime noise from a participant audio for conference purpose?

Tags: audio, noise, audio-processing, noise-cancellation

I am new to audio signal processing and I wanna do real-time noise cancelation for a participant in a conference.

I am capturing audio at 16bit, 16khz, little-endian config. I tried to use the webRTC noise cancelation module as always but failed to integrate it. I have found some other solutions out there like RNN(Recurrent Neural Network) based [solution](https://gitlab.xiph.org/xiph/rnnoise) but don't know how to use them, if I can, is there a way to do it on the server side? Also tried Noisetorch(only for ubuntu).
So my question is what is the best approach or open-source solution available to this problem to date out there and please suggest to me if I have to look into some areas like FFT or others. My main constraint is dynamic noise range and real-time voice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions requesting working code written to a specification are off-topic as they are unlikely to benefit anyone else.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem to solve. You could start with some freeware solutions like Audacity or Veed,io and see if any of them does what you want and then deep dive into their algorithms (provided it's legal to do so).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I asked about suggestions as I am new to this topic. And noise cancellation is not just about a piece of code I guess. Firstly I have to learn some theories, then try some snippets, then you can expect me to post some broken code asking how to fix them. I mainly wanted that guideline about theories or some snippets which could help in this regard. Hilmar helped me with AGC like this in another question and thanks to him.

Comment: @NafiulAlamFuji that is very admirable! doing anything *live* might really not be the easiest entry to the field. Denoising is hard enough as is! So, start slow. Looking forward to your questions!